# How to transform this hexagonal vertices to round / circle vertices arrangement

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, faces, vertex-groups

I am wonder if is there a trick in blender to transform this "cubit" cylinder to a "circle"
cylinder?
I created the cylinder with only 16 vertices, in edit mode I subdivided for 3 times, now this is the result. I know that the right way is to apply subdivision surface, but I am wonder if it is possible to transform the hexagonal vertices to a perfect circle.

[image]

Here it the blend file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lzy8QVktv-BLOQb22_fA-mJ12VbM7H_H/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternative to @moonboots
In this case you could use the free looptools plug-in (enable in preferences).
Select all the edge rings, and select circle in the looptools options list, see below

From:
[image]

To:
[image]

In future, when you subdivide a mesh like this and want it to be smooth after subdividing in edit mode, go with: select all edges, edges (dropdown menu) > subdivide > smoothness to 1

See below:
[image]

I hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

A couple of alternatives to @moonboots' perfectly good answer..

- The *Subdivide* operator has a 'Smooth' option in its <kbd>F9</kbd> panel. If that had been set to 1, your cylinder would have been circular when you subdivided it.
- The *Cast* modifier, 'Cylinder' option.  This works only in local space, and will not be affected by any rotation of an  'Object' you may select to be its transform origin. So it only works if the modified object's Z is from end to end of the cylinder, and the modifier is set to deform in X and Y. Pretty useless. You could write a better one in Geometry Nodes.
- *Loop Tools > Circle* on all around-loops, selected.

Answer (score 5):

Select all the circle edges (to make it quick, select an edge ring then *Select > Select Loops > Edge Loops*), choose *Transform Pivot Point > Individual Origins*, then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *To Sphere* and drag (go into the *Operator* box if you want to make sure it is at 1):

[image]